# How to get file descriptor number of a output and how to redirect all of them at once

Tags: shell, io-redirection, output, file-descriptors, time-utility

Lets take this command for example

```
$ time ssh ec2 ls
www apps
real    0m0.554s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ssh ec2 ls 1>/dev/null
real    0m0.554s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time ssh ec2 ls 2>/dev/null
www apps
real    0m0.554s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Clearly `ls` output come from `fd 1`. What about `time` output. Which file descriptor does it use? How can I find it?

Other than this, instead of redirectly them individually, how can I redirect all of them at once.. i.e. `all>/dev/null`. I am not looking for `1>/dev/null 2>&1...`

Answer (score 1):

`time` writes to stderr.

The reason it appears not to is that you are writing the stderr of the current command to `/dev/null`, not the output of time. This is because `time` is a keyword that's parsed differently from regular utilities: the redirection is part of the timed command.

Using a code block redirects all output.

```
{ time ls; } 2> /dev/null
```

Note that you can still redirect the output of ls somewhere else inside the block if you want and this will be timed.

To redirect everything you can do

```
{ time ls 1>&2; } 2> /dev/null
```